# About "AUTOMATIC TEXT SUMMARIZER (lingustic based)"

Tags: text, nlp, linguistics, summarization

I am having "AUTOMATIC TEXT SUMMARIZER (linguistic approach)" as my final year project. I have collected enough research papers and gone through them. Still I am not very clear about the 'how-to-go-for-it' thing. Basically I found "AUTOMATIC TEXT SUMMARIZER (statistical based)" and found that it is much easier compared to my project. My project guide told me not to opt this (statistical based) and to go for linguistic based.

Anyone who has ever worked upon or even heard of this sort of project would be knowing that summarizing any document means nothing but SCORING each sentence (by some approach involving some specific algos) and then selecting sentences having score more than threshold score. Now the most difficult part of this project is choosing the appropriate algorithm for scoring and later implementing it.

I have moderate programming skills and would like to code in JAVA (because there I'll get lots of APIs resulting in lesser overheads). Now I want to know that for my project, what should be my approach and algos used. Also how to implement them.

Comment: This is unanswerable.  What sort of criteria do you want to score sentences on?

Comment: Since this show up on Google, I will point to this project which implements various algorithm for text summarization https://github.com/miso-belica/sumy

Answer (score 5):

[Using Lexical Chains for Text Summarization (Microsoft Research)](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cyl/download/papers/lexical-chains.pdf)

An analysis of different algorithms: [DasMartins.2007](http://www.ark.cs.cmu.edu/LS2/images/9/90/DasMartins.2007.pdf)

Most important part in the doc:

> • Nenkova (2005) analyzes that no system
>   could beat the baseline with statistical
>   significance
>   • Striking result!

Note there are 2 different nuances to the **liguistic** approach:

- Linguistic rating system (all clear here)
- Linguistic generation (rewrites sentences to build the summary)

Answer (score 2):

Automatic Summarization is a pretty complex area - try to get your java skills first in order as well as your understanding of statistical NLP which uses machine learning. You can then work through building something of substance. Evaluate your solution and make sure you have concretely defined your measurement variables and how you went about your evaluation. Otherwise, your project is doomed to failure. This is generally considered a high risk project for final year undergraduate students as they often are unable to get the principles right and then implement it in a way that is not right either and then their evaluation measures are all ill defined and don't reflect on their own work clearly. My advice would be to focus on one area rather then many in summarization as you can have single and multi document summaries. The more varied you make your project the less likely hold of you receiving a good mark. Keep it focused and in depth. Evaluate other peoples work then the process you decided to take and outcomes of that.

Readings:
-Jurafsky book on NLP there is a back section on summarization and QA.
-Advances in Text Summarization by inderjeet mani is really good

Understand what things like term weighting, centroid based summarization, log-likelihood ratio, coherence relations, sentence simplification, maximum marginal relevance, redundancy, and what a focused summary actually is.

You can attempt it using a supervised or an unsupervised approach as well as a hybrid.
Linguistic is a safer option that is why you have been advised to take that approach.
Try attempting it linguistically then build statistical on to hybridize your solution.
Use it as an exercise to learn the theory and practical implication of the algorithms as well as build on your knowledge. As you will no doubt have to explain and defend your project to the judging panel.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have read those research papers and research books you probably know what is known. Now it is up to you to implement the knowledge of those research papers and research books in a Java application. Or you could expand the human knowledge by doing some innovation/invention. If you do expand human knowledge you have become a true scientist.

Answer (score 0):

Please make your question more specific, in these two main areas:

1. Project definition: What is the goal of your project? 
   Is the input unit a single document? A list of documents? 
   Do you intend your program to use machine learning?
   What is the output?
   How will you measure success?
2. Your background knowledge: You intend to use linguistic rather than statistical methods.
   Do you have background in parsing natural language? In semantic representation?
   I think some of these questions are tough. I am asking them because I spent too much time trying to answer similar questions in the course of my studies. Once you get these sorted out, I may be able to give you some pointers. [Mani's "Automatic Summarization"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1588110605) looks like a good start, at least the introductory chapters.

Answer (score 0):

The University of Sheffield did some work on [automatic email summarising](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1220498) as part of the EU FASiL project a few years back.